# Convert HL7 RIM to SQL Table Structure

Tags: sql, database-design, data-modeling, hl7

Am I looking at this RIM thing wrong?  Does anyone know where I can find the HL7 RIM model as a sql table structure?  I've looked through all the files in http://www.hl7.org/implement/standards/rim.cfm and cannot find one that would easily lend itself. It seems like this should be easy?

Comment: have u found an answer?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing and this is for purpose. By trying to convert RIM to the database you may end up significantly de-normalizing your initial structure. You may look at openEHR (and HL7 FHIR) instead.

(You may find "Unofficial Developer's Guide to HL7v3 Basics" helpful to understand the RIM. The book is available at - hl7basics.shamilpublishing.com)

Comment: which file can be used to convert it to SQL?

Comment: "Which file" of what?

Comment: I downloaded the file from http://www.hl7.org/implement/standards/rim.cfm , but i could not find the file that is related to the database structure and can be converted into SQL file

Comment: The archive you've downloaded contains MIF files used by RMIMDesigner. To handle those you need RoseTree (http://gforge.hl7.org/gf/project/rose-tree/frs/). The resulted database is specific to generating R-MIM models, not to store HL7v3 message content.

Comment: i have use rosetree actually to generate the tree, but i am not sure how to convert it into mysql, do you know how to do it?

Comment: Take the original MIFs and generate from those. You may also check MARC-HI Everest Framework that works with MIF files.

Comment: how to generate it? can i automate the generation process or i have to do it manually?

Comment: can i know where can i get the sample data of hl7 rim?

Comment: MIF files are generated by RMIMDesigner from the message model(s).

Answer (score 0):

RIM based content is typically encoded as XML documents. Rather than trying to shred it out into a normalized relational schema you may get better results by storing the whole XML document in a single database field and then query it using XQuery. All the major commercial relational databases have pretty good support for this now.

Answer (score 0):

HL7 v3 RIM is the base model for all v3 standards, is not a persistence model. HL7 v3 is a family of standards, including messaging and clinical document specification for different domains.

Of course you can represent the HL7 RIM in a SQL schema, since a mapping can be done, but is not the purpose of the HL7.

If you need to create a clinical data repository, start with your requirements, design a schema, then map RIM into your schema, but don't use the RIM as your database schema.

Comment: "Of course you can represent the HL7 RIM in a SQL schema, since a mapping can be done, but is not the purpose of the HL7." but could i know how to do it? only for researching purpose, thaks

Comment: @RobertLimanto you need to create tables for each of the classes of the RIM, and columns for every single attribute, there is no out of the box solution. Also take a look at Object Relational Mapping. Basically, the CDA model can be seen as an OO model, so with an ORM framework, the schema can be generated from the OO model. Again, you will need to actually write code for the model and maybe for the ORM.

Comment: how many tables are there? 
could we just convert one of the file that store the structure to sql file? if yes, which file is that?

Comment: @RobertLimanto you mean how many classes? Tables is what you should create, so it is not possible to know how many you will end up having. You'll need to count the classes of the RIM+datatypes v3 models, and the amount of tables corresponding to those classes will depend on the ORM strategy and your implementation. Creating a SQL manually is the worst way of implementing this. I mentioned using an ORM framework.